# Subclassing, NVI

Tags: c#, .net

Should the following be considered wtf code?

```
abstract class BaseCat
{
    public virtual void SayMiau()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MIAU!");
    }
}

class StrangeCat : BaseCat
{
    private readonly bool _canMiau;

    public StrangeCat(bool canMiau)
    {
        _canMiau = canMiau;
    }

    public override void SayMiau()
    {
        if (_canMiau)
        {
            base.SayMiau();
        }
    }
}
```

What's the right approach here? [Non-virtual interfaces](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) (NVI)?

Comment: Relevant discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340487/is-the-non-virtual-interface-nvi-idiom-as-useful-in-c-as-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you show has no rationale for the BaseCat being abstract, make it non-abstract and your example makes perfect sense. Though I would make a strong case that your BaseCat may want to implement the structure of StrangeCat. Then have StrangeCat merely implement a change to the _canMiau if valid.

```
public class BaseCat
{
    protected bool _canMiau;

    // if you wanted abstract so BaseCat could not be constructed make the constructor protected
    protected BaseCat(bool canMiau) { _canMiau = canMiau; }

    public virtual void SayMiau()
    {
        if (_canMiau)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MIAU!");
        }
    }
}

public class StrangeCat : BaseCat
{
    public StrangeCat(bool canMiau) : base(canMiau) { }
}

public class MuteCat : BaseCat
{
    public MuteCat() : base(false) { }
}

public class LoudCat : BaseCat
{
    public LoudCat() : base(true) { }
}
```

Then when you kick the cat, it will respond appropriately with minimal duplication of logic. I would avoid an abstract class unless the inheritors are going to implement significant logic differences, your example doesn't show that (though your real situation may have that).

```
public void KickCat(BaseCat)
{
    Foot.StraightTowardsCat(BaseCat, Anatomy.Rear);
    BaseCat.SayMiau();
}

...

KickCat(new MuteCat()); // I love this cat, it's like it doesn't even care!
KickCat(new LoudCat()); // Whines, blah.
KickCat(new StrangeCat(true)); // Whines this time.
KickCat(new StrangeCat(false)); // Doesn't whine this time! Woot!
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should.
It breaks the Liskov substitution principle.

I don't know what is the NVI, but I think that the right approach in this particular case would be
to create a sub class NormalCat: BaseCat and move the method SayMiau() to this class.